# Modifying existing resources from puppet

Tags: puppet, devops

We are implementing a puppet module for a storage subsystem. We are implementing our own types and providers and we will have types like volume, host etc related to the storage subsystem.

We have made our types ensurable and creation and deletion are working fine.

Our question is, how to implement the modification of an existing resource?
Suppose a volume resource has been created and now I want to change the expiration hours of the volume, how do I implement this in my provider?
Is it by creating a new ensure value like modify or is there some other way?

Comment: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_resources_advanced.html#adding-or-modifying-attributes

Comment: I don't think that's what he's asking about, @MattSchuchard.  He appears to want to know about provider implementation and modifying *physical* resources, not DSL-level attribute manipulation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I understand, but my opinion is that explaining a way to do it is better than just answering "you cannot/should not do this".

Comment: No, @MattSchuchard, I don't think you *do* understand.  I'm saying you responded to a different question than the one the OP asked.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, that is what I interpreted your comment to mean, ergo I do understand and simply had a different opinion on the course of action and why I left a comment instead of writing out what I felt would be a poor answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to implement the modification of an existing resource? Suppose a
>   volume resource has been created and now I want to change the
>   expiration hours of the volume, how do I implement this in my
>   provider? Is it by creating a new ensure value like modify or is there
>   some other way?

No, you do not create a special `ensure` value.  That would be hard to work with, because it would require that your manifests be aware of whether the resource needs to be created.  Remember always that your manifests describe the target state of each resource, irrespective (to a first approximation) of their current state or even whether they exist.

The custom type documentation is a little vague here, however, because the implementation is basically open.  You can do whatever makes sense for you.  But there are two particularly common models:

- the provider's property setter methods (also) modify the physical resource's properties if they are out of sync, on a property-by-property basis.
- the provider implements [flushing](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/provider_development.html#flushing), so resource properties are synchronized with the system directly or indirectly by the provider's `flush` method

Comment: Yes, seems like we can use the flush method to modify an existing resource, In our case we call a Rest API, our primary concern was when to call POST (create) and when to call PUT (modify). Now we are thinking of tracking property changes and call modify in the flush method.